# I use yum to install the vsftpd. Why is it not located in `/etc/rc.d/init.d/`?

Tags: centos, yum, vsftpd

My yum source is local iso source, and I use `yum install vsftpd -y`,
I use `whereis` find the `vsftpd`:

```
[root@localhost etc]#  whereis vsftpd
vsftpd: /usr/sbin/vsftpd /etc/vsftpd /usr/share/man/man8/vsftpd.8.gz
```

It turns out under the `/usr/sbin/`, why it do not locate in the `/etc/rc.d/init.d`?

---

**EDIT**

I use `CentOS 7.2`.

Comment: Which Linux distribution are you using?

Comment: @roaima See my EDIT, I use CentOS 7.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/etc/init.d` or `/etc/rc.d/init.d` is, where the initialization scripts for the software applications reside. `/usr/sbin` (or `/usr/bin`) is where the application executables are actually installed.

`/etc/rc.d/init.d` just contains a script to invoke the application (in your case vsftpd). The script is usually used to start application as a daemon service during boot up by the **init** process. In addition to this, scripts in `/etc/init.d` provide start, stop, status and restart options.

vsftpd is the application and it usually has a service file in `/etc/systemd/system/` instead of a startup script. That's why it's not located in `/etc/init.d/`

Comment: Great answer, other than that the service in the vsftpd package is `/usr/lib/systemd/system/vsftpd.service`.

Answer (score 0):

Because if you read `man whereis`, it only searches for binaries in the standard `$PATH`.  E.g.

```
# echo $PATH
/usr/lib64/ccache:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin
```

Notice that `/etc/init.d` is not in `PATH`.

You could look through all the files installed by the vsftpd RPM using `rpm -q --dump vsftpd`.

As pointed out by @Gilson_Varghese, there won't necessarily be a script in `/etc/init.d`.  There might only be a systemd unit.  If there are both, systemd will only use the systemd unit!  Packages will install systemd units into `/lib/systemd/system/` (not `/etc` !), with a `.service` file extension.